# Zsh: Put all non-global parameters to anonymous/local inner function

Tags: zsh

Correct me if this statement is wrong: All variables/parameters that defined inside a zsh script keep its persistent scope globally in current shell session.

If above statement is true, then to avoid messing around the current shell's environment variables / other zsh scripts. Should we put all variables/parameters of a zsh script to anonymous/local inner function if possible?

The possibilities can be counted as:

1. We use that variables right away in that local scope => anonymous function
2. Mark their scope by using maker `always` => inner func using `always`
3. Mark but using rarely used traps to mark => inner func using traps

The question and the purpose is that all variables/parameters must local inside a zsh script and must be destroyed after used inside that zsh script.

EDIT: I did confuse about runing and sourcing shell script.

I want to `source` a script inside a script but try to keep minimizing affect of the sourcing script to mess the calling script's environment.

@Stéphane Chazelas did answer the question but I'd to make it clear as I understand, correct if I'm wrong.

Running a shell script inside a shell script `./script.zsh` will invoke new shell to run the script then return exit code to the calling script.

Sourcing a shell script inside a shell script `. ./script.zsh` will create a sub-process of the current shell and any changes - define new variables, functions.. will be put in the current shell's environment, this is expected behavior because mostly user want to use them after sourcing process but you can exclude unwanted portions by using anonymous funcion like @Stéphane Chazelas mentioned in comment. With note that `alias` always comes up with global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you execute a script, your shell forks a new process in which the interpreter of that script is executed to interpret the content of that script.

Any variable assignment will only affect the shell variables of *that* shell invocation in *that* process. Once that process dies, the variables of the calling shell will not have been affected.

The only exception I know to that is with the `fish` shell when using `set -U var value` to define `fish` *universal variables*, where `fish` passes the variable value using some IPC mechanism between processes running `fish` and use permanent storage to retain the value of the variable when no `fish` process is running.

Now when you *source* a script (as opposed to *execute* it) with the `.` or `source` builtin command within your shell, then you tell *your* shell to interpret code in that script (there is no sub-process involved here, `. ./script.zsh` is similar to `eval "$(<script.zsh)"`). But then you generally only use `source` when you *do* want variable assignments there to affect your shell, like when *sourcing* environment files.

Now you can imagine scripts meant to be sourced in which you want some *variables*, *functions*, *aliases*... to be defined in the invoking shell, but some that are only helper variables that are not. And then yes, you could use an anonymous function with local scope like:

```
myfunc() echo hi # function meant to be defined for the invoker
myvar=value  # same for a variable

(){ local i # i variable local
  for i in foo bar
    alias $i='echo x' # alias defined globally
  done
}
```

(note that zsh only implements local scope for variables and options, not for functions, aliases...)

Comment: I did confuse about running and sourcing shell script, did edit the post.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. The `universal scope` in `Fish` is interesting!